# Spark streaming : WAL ignored

Tags: apache-spark, jms, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

I have a spark streaming application running on yarn that consumes from a jms source. I have the checkpointing and WAL enabled to ensure zero data loss. 
However, When I suddenly kill my application and restarts it, sometimes it recovers the data from the WAL but sometimes it doesn’t !! In all the cases, I can see the WAL written correctly on HDFS.

Can someone explains me why my WAL is sometimes ignored on restart ? What are the conditions for spark to decide to recover or not from the WAL ?

Thanks.